# Backbone.js - validating model constructor parameters

Tags: validation, parameters, backbone.js, constructor

I want to do simple thing with a model:

- use constructor parameters if they are valid (but not just assign them, I have to map them before as they are in a different format)
- in other case, use `defaults`

What's the recomended solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by calling `isValid()` in `initialize`.  If it's valid, then proceed as normal; otherwise, clear the model and reset it with the default values:

```
initialize: function() {
    console.log("initializing model...");
    if (!this.isValid()) {
        console.log("Model is not valid, using defaults");
        this.clear({ silent: true });
        this.set(this.defaults, { silent: true });
    }
    console.log("Model is valid");
},
```

[See this working demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/N3vmg/)

**Edit**

It's possible to use objects in the model constructor, for example:

```
var model = new Backbone.Model({
    title: "test",
    hsa: {
        h: 120,
        s: "100%",
        a: "50%"
    }
});
```

You could also specify it as `hsa: "120, 100%, 50%"` or something, and convert that value to an object in the constructor.

[See here.](http://jsfiddle.net/7KpTQ/1/)

Comment: That's great! Now I only have to solve problem with customizing constructor. You see, some of properties I pass to the constructor are hex colors. Instance of model contains not strings, but objects (in HSL color space). I have already defaults with these objects, but arguments are just a strings.

Comment: @ciembor that should be no problem -- you can pass objects into the constructor.  Or you can write a function to extract attributes and convert them ... either way works.  See my update above.

Comment: Yes, I know I can. I just wanted to do it properly, with no loose functions or abstract methods:). But who cares, I will do that like you said:D.